# How to show uniform convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, infinity

Let $$f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty ke^{-t\sqrt{k}}u_k$$ for $t \in (0,\infty)$, where the $u_k$ is such that $\sum \sqrt{k}u_k$ converges, but we know nothing about the convergence of $\sum ku_k$.

How do I show that the partial sums that make $f(t)$ converge uniformly to $f(t)$ for $t \in (0, \infty)$?

I can't apply Abel's test since it is not monotone.

Comment: Where the $u_k$ are constants? If it's possible that $\sum ku_k=\infty$ then the sum cannot converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$. Uniformly on compact subsets, fine...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Are you sure it cannot? I thought the exponential damping term would help.. Yes $u_k$ are constants.

Comment: The exponential damping term helps less and less and $t$ tends to $0$, approaching no help at all in the limit. "Rigorously": If the sum converges uniformly on $(0,,\infty)$ then it follows that $f$ actually extends to a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$. But if $u_k\ge0$ then $f(t)$ tends to $\sum ku_k$ as $t$ decreases to $0$.

Comment: The statement should be indeed true to be proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is true. For example, take $u_{k}=\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{3/4}}$.

Of course, you can show that the series converges uniformly on subsets of $R^{+}$ of the form $[a,\infty )$ if you write

$f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty ke^{-t\sqrt{k}}u_k=f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sqrt{k}u_k(\sqrt{k}e^{-t\sqrt{k}})$

and use the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: Sorry but what are you bounding the term with for the Weierstrass test?

Comment: @ChrisAl: $\sqrt{x}e^{-t\sqrt{x}} \leq \sqrt{x}e^{-a\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{1}{a}e^{-a}$